# ¿Cómo saco un request de un formulario con prefijo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-requests

En mi página principal tengo dos formularios con prefijos para diferenciarlos:

```
context['login_form'] = LogInForm(prefix='login')
context['signIn_form'] = SignInForm(prefix='signin')
```

Al rellenar un formulario y enviarlo (por ejemplo el de registro) me quedan los siguientes campos en request:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken: 'M5NGRWWRJfGIFY0l0kKfTJLz05HY85MW2vbZ7mhwAv0tO2Hnw4MA4PZ914cMPsTt'
signin-email: 'and@gmail.com'
signin-password: '123'
signin-repeat_password: '123'
checkbox: 'check'
SignInButton: ''
```

pero no puedo sacar el campo email de la siguiente forma: `request.signin-email` porque tiene un `-`.

¿Cómo puedo obtener los valores de ese request?

Gracias.

Comment: Acabo de encontrar la solución:

    signin_email = request.POST.get('signin-email')

Comment: en efecto eso se define de acuerdo a como este tu metodo del form post o get.....request.POST.get('mi_campo) o request.GET('mi_campo'), es recomentable usar tanto id y name para los inputs en caso de no usar los forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

desde el request de django no es posible obtener los parametros directamente si necesitas obtenerlo tienes que usar el metodo desde el cual lo envias ejemplo GET, POST y obtenerlo como un diccionario, ejemplo:

```
email = request.POST.get("signin-email")
```